# Wavelength of an electron removed from an atom of hydrogen

Tags: electrons

I have the following exercise:

> Determine the wavelength of an electron removed from an atom of hydrogen, in gas state, by a photon of wavelength of 45 nm.

So what I immediately thought was to apply De Broglie equation having

$ \lambda_{electron} = \frac{h}{m_{electron} v_{electron}}=\frac{h}{\sqrt {2 m_{electron} K_{electron}}}$

Ok then I thought that I need to calculate the kinetics energy of the electron.

Well if this was the photoelectric experiment with a metal we would have:

$K = h\nu - W$

But this is an atom we don't have an extraction energy W. Should I use the 1st ionization energy or is there other formula for calculating the kinetics energy of the electron.

Thanks!!

Comment: Yes, use the 1st ionization energy.

Comment: Hi! It can't be because I get to a negative kinetics energy

Comment: Then you are doing it wrong. How much is your $h\nu$, to begin with? How much is your $W$?

Comment: You're right, I got 1 calculation wrong. Thanks!

Comment: You should answer you own question so that it may be useful to future users.